# I am trying to include the title into one line

Tags: tables

I have the following longtable thanks to the community's feedback and documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{ r *{7}{l} }
  \caption{Simultaneously Amplified or Deleted Genes in Claudin-Low Breast Cancer}\label{tab:genes}\\
  \hline
  & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End \\ 
  \hline
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{8}{c}{Table \ref{tab:genes}, continued}\\[1ex]
  \hline
 & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & qValue \\ 
  \hline
  \endhead
  \hline
  \multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{(continued on next page)}
  \endfoot
  \hline\hline
  \endlastfoot
1 & A26B1 & protein expressed in prostate, ovary, testis, & 15q11.2 & 15 & 19305252 & 19336667 \\

2 & APOD & apolipoprotein D precursor & 3q29 & 3 & 196776864 & 196792278 \\

3 & DOK6 & docking protein 6 & 18q23 & 18 & 65219270 & 65660359 \\

4 & FLJ20433 & hypothetical protein LOC54932 & 9q34.3 & 9 & 139321168 & 139437535 \\

5 & FLT3 & fms-related tyrosine kinase 3 & 13q12.2 & 13 & 27475410 & 27572729 \\

6 & hsa-mir-570 & hsa-mir-570 & 3q29 & 3 & 196911451 & 196911548 \\

7 & LOC283755 & hypothetical protein LOC283755 & 15q11.2 & 15 & 18848557 & 18971443 \\

8 & LOC283767 & hypothetical protein LOC283767 & 15q11.2 & 15 & 20287609 & 20296164 \\

9 & LOC650137 & seven transmembrane helix receptor & 15q11.2 & 15 & 19915065 & 19915749 \\

10 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform L & 3q29 & 3 & 196933423 & 196950211 \\

11 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform S & 3q29 & 3 & 196936768 & 196950211 \\

12 & OR11H12 & olfactory receptor, family 11, subfamily H, & 14q11.1 & 14 & 18447593 & 18448574 \\

13 & OR4M2 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily M, & 15q11.2 & 15 & 19869939 & 19870881 \\

14 & OR4N4 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily N, & 15q11.2 & 15 & 19883836 & 19884787 \\

15 & PIK3CA & phosphoinositide-3-kinase, catalytic, alpha & 3q26.32 & 3 & 180349004 & 180435191 \\

16 & TMPRSS11E & transmembrane protease, serine 11E & 4q13.2.1 & 4 & 68995761 & 69045917 \\

17 & TMPRSS11E2 & transmembrane protease, serine 11E2 & 4q13.2.1 & 4 & 68995761 & 69045917 \\

18 & UGT2B15 & UDP glycosyltransferase 2 family, polypeptide & 4q13.2.1 & 4 & 69194909 & 69218969 \\

19 & UGT2B17 & UDP glucuronosyltransferase 2 family, & 4q13.2.1 & 4 & 69085497 & 69116840 \\

20 & ZDHHC11 & zinc finger, DHHC-type containing 11 & 5p15.33 & 5 & 848721 & 904101 \\
\hline
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

If you run the code, you will see that the tile doesn't fit quite nicely into one line, and there is a lot of white space at the end. I'm pretty sure that it's something stupid that I am not seeing. Thank you!

[image: longtable]

Comment: Your screenshot makes it look like you compiled the document only once. Try recompiling and check that the caption and the header are properly formatted.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is to include `\usepackage{caption}` in the preamble.

My original guess was that without it, it used `\textwidth`, rather than `\linewidth` for the caption width since, during rotated text, the former is not changed, but the latter is.  But as John K. points out in the comments, the actual width of the default caption is significantly narrower than the value of `\textwidth`.

The comment by Arash E. Correctly diagnoses the length associated with the caption when the `caption` package is not used.  It is `\LTcapwidth` (i.e., longtable caption width).  I give an MWE at the end to demonstrate this.

In any event, the remedy is achieved through the use of the `caption` package, which properly sets the caption width to the available `\linewidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{ r *{7}{l} }
  \caption{Simultaneously Amplified or Deleted Genes in Claudin-Low Breast Cancer}\label{tab:genes}\\
  \hline
  & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End \\ 
  \hline
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{8}{c}{Table \ref{tab:genes}, continued}\\[1ex]
  \hline
 & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & qValue \\ 
  \hline
  \endhead
  \hline
  \multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{(continued on next page)}
  \endfoot
  \hline\hline
  \endlastfoot
1 & A26B1 & protein expressed in prostate, ovary, testis, & 15q11.2 & 15 & 19305252 & 19336667 \\

2 & APOD & apolipoprotein D precursor & 3q29 & 3 & 196776864 & 196792278 \\

3 & DOK6 & docking protein 6 & 18q23 & 18 & 65219270 & 65660359 \\

4 & FLJ20433 & hypothetical protein LOC54932 & 9q34.3 & 9 & 139321168 & 139437535 \\

5 & FLT3 & fms-related tyrosine kinase 3 & 13q12.2 & 13 & 27475410 & 27572729 \\

6 & hsa-mir-570 & hsa-mir-570 & 3q29 & 3 & 196911451 & 196911548 \\

7 & LOC283755 & hypothetical protein LOC283755 & 15q11.2 & 15 & 18848557 & 18971443 \\

8 & LOC283767 & hypothetical protein LOC283767 & 15q11.2 & 15 & 20287609 & 20296164 \\

9 & LOC650137 & seven transmembrane helix receptor & 15q11.2 & 15 & 19915065 & 19915749 \\

10 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform L & 3q29 & 3 & 196933423 & 196950211 \\

11 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform S & 3q29 & 3 & 196936768 & 196950211 \\

12 & OR11H12 & olfactory receptor, family 11, subfamily H, & 14q11.1 & 14 & 18447593 & 18448574 \\

13 & OR4M2 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily M, & 15q11.2 & 15 & 19869939 & 19870881 \\

14 & OR4N4 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily N, & 15q11.2 & 15 & 19883836 & 19884787 \\

15 & PIK3CA & phosphoinositide-3-kinase, catalytic, alpha & 3q26.32 & 3 & 180349004 & 180435191 \\

16 & TMPRSS11E & transmembrane protease, serine 11E & 4q13.2.1 & 4 & 68995761 & 69045917 \\

17 & TMPRSS11E2 & transmembrane protease, serine 11E2 & 4q13.2.1 & 4 & 68995761 & 69045917 \\

18 & UGT2B15 & UDP glycosyltransferase 2 family, polypeptide & 4q13.2.1 & 4 & 69194909 & 69218969 \\

19 & UGT2B17 & UDP glucuronosyltransferase 2 family, & 4q13.2.1 & 4 & 69085497 & 69116840 \\

20 & ZDHHC11 & zinc finger, DHHC-type containing 11 & 5p15.33 & 5 & 848721 & 904101 \\
\hline
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Following up on Arash E's suggestion regarding `\LTcapwidth`, I was able to verify that with this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
{\centering\rule{\the\LTcapwidth}{1pt}\par}
\begin{longtable}{ r *{7}{l} }
  \caption{\the\LTcapwidth{} is the LTcapwidth.  The above rule is that width. Simultaneously Amplified or Deleted Genes in Claudin-Low Breast Cancer}\label{tab:genes}\\
  \hline
  & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End \\ 
  \hline
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{8}{c}{Table \ref{tab:genes}, continued}\\[1ex]
  \hline
 & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & qValue \\ 
  \hline
  \endhead
  \hline
  \multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{(continued on next page)}
  \endfoot
  \hline\hline
  \endlastfoot
1 & A26B1 & protein expressed in prostate, ovary, testis, & 15q11.2 & 15 & 19305252 & 19336667 \\

2 & APOD & apolipoprotein D precursor & 3q29 & 3 & 196776864 & 196792278 \\

3 & DOK6 & docking protein 6 & 18q23 & 18 & 65219270 & 65660359 \\

4 & FLJ20433 & hypothetical protein LOC54932 & 9q34.3 & 9 & 139321168 & 139437535 \\

5 & FLT3 & fms-related tyrosine kinase 3 & 13q12.2 & 13 & 27475410 & 27572729 \\

6 & hsa-mir-570 & hsa-mir-570 & 3q29 & 3 & 196911451 & 196911548 \\

7 & LOC283755 & hypothetical protein LOC283755 & 15q11.2 & 15 & 18848557 & 18971443 \\

8 & LOC283767 & hypothetical protein LOC283767 & 15q11.2 & 15 & 20287609 & 20296164 \\

9 & LOC650137 & seven transmembrane helix receptor & 15q11.2 & 15 & 19915065 & 19915749 \\

10 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform L & 3q29 & 3 & 196933423 & 196950211 \\

11 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform S & 3q29 & 3 & 196936768 & 196950211 \\

12 & OR11H12 & olfactory receptor, family 11, subfamily H, & 14q11.1 & 14 & 18447593 & 18448574 \\

13 & OR4M2 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily M, & 15q11.2 & 15 & 19869939 & 19870881 \\

14 & OR4N4 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily N, & 15q11.2 & 15 & 19883836 & 19884787 \\

15 & PIK3CA & phosphoinositide-3-kinase, catalytic, alpha & 3q26.32 & 3 & 180349004 & 180435191 \\

16 & TMPRSS11E & transmembrane protease, serine 11E & 4q13.2.1 & 4 & 68995761 & 69045917 \\

17 & TMPRSS11E2 & transmembrane protease, serine 11E2 & 4q13.2.1 & 4 & 68995761 & 69045917 \\

18 & UGT2B15 & UDP glycosyltransferase 2 family, polypeptide & 4q13.2.1 & 4 & 69194909 & 69218969 \\

19 & UGT2B17 & UDP glucuronosyltransferase 2 family, & 4q13.2.1 & 4 & 69085497 & 69116840 \\

20 & ZDHHC11 & zinc finger, DHHC-type containing 11 & 5p15.33 & 5 & 848721 & 904101 \\
\hline
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is a limit on the default caption, but it appears to be much smaller than \textwidth.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Confirmed.

Comment: I searched all the sty files, but the only name which popped up was \cap@width, and that wasn't it.

Comment: @JohnKormylo - Are you looking for `\LTcapwidth=\textwidth`?

Comment: @ArashEsbati Thank you for the correct diagnosis.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Arash was correct.  See my supplemental MWE to verify it.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - You're welcome.  Regarding `longtable` and captions, there is also `ltcaption` with some nice features.  Just in case you are not aware of it.

Answer (score 2):

Does is it help if you tweak the value of `\LTcapwidth`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}

\setlength\LTcapwidth{0.9\textwidth}% <=====

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{ r *{7}{l} }
  \caption{Simultaneously Amplified or Deleted Genes in Claudin-Low
    Breast Cancer -- Simultaneously Amplified or Deleted Genes in
    Claudin-Low Breast Cancer -- Simultaneously Amplified or Deleted
    Genes in Claudin-Low Breast Cancer}\label{tab:genes}\\
  \hline
  & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End \\ 
  \hline
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{8}{c}{Table \ref{tab:genes}, continued}\\[1ex]
  \hline
 & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & qValue \\ 
  \hline
  \endhead
  \hline
  \multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{(continued on next page)}
  \endfoot
  \hline\hline
  \endlastfoot
1 & A26B1 & protein expressed in prostate, ovary, testis, & 15q11.2 & 15 & 19305252 & 19336667 \\

2 & APOD & apolipoprotein D precursor & 3q29 & 3 & 196776864 & 196792278 \\

3 & DOK6 & docking protein 6 & 18q23 & 18 & 65219270 & 65660359 \\

4 & FLJ20433 & hypothetical protein LOC54932 & 9q34.3 & 9 & 139321168 & 139437535 \\

5 & FLT3 & fms-related tyrosine kinase 3 & 13q12.2 & 13 & 27475410 & 27572729 \\

6 & hsa-mir-570 & hsa-mir-570 & 3q29 & 3 & 196911451 & 196911548 \\

7 & LOC283755 & hypothetical protein LOC283755 & 15q11.2 & 15 & 18848557 & 18971443 \\

8 & LOC283767 & hypothetical protein LOC283767 & 15q11.2 & 15 & 20287609 & 20296164 \\

9 & LOC650137 & seven transmembrane helix receptor & 15q11.2 & 15 & 19915065 & 19915749 \\

10 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform L & 3q29 & 3 & 196933423 & 196950211 \\

11 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform S & 3q29 & 3 & 196936768 & 196950211 \\

12 & OR11H12 & olfactory receptor, family 11, subfamily H, & 14q11.1 & 14 & 18447593 & 18448574 \\

13 & OR4M2 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily M, & 15q11.2 & 15 & 19869939 & 19870881 \\

14 & OR4N4 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily N, & 15q11.2 & 15 & 19883836 & 19884787 \\

15 & PIK3CA & phosphoinositide-3-kinase, catalytic, alpha & 3q26.32 & 3 & 180349004 & 180435191 \\

16 & TMPRSS11E & transmembrane protease, serine 11E & 4q13.2.1 & 4 & 68995761 & 69045917 \\

17 & TMPRSS11E2 & transmembrane protease, serine 11E2 & 4q13.2.1 & 4 & 68995761 & 69045917 \\

18 & UGT2B15 & UDP glycosyltransferase 2 family, polypeptide & 4q13.2.1 & 4 & 69194909 & 69218969 \\

19 & UGT2B17 & UDP glucuronosyltransferase 2 family, & 4q13.2.1 & 4 & 69085497 & 69116840 \\

20 & ZDHHC11 & zinc finger, DHHC-type containing 11 & 5p15.33 & 5 & 848721 & 904101 \\
\hline
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]